# Comparing two strings in Python not showing the intended result

Tags: python, string, csv

This is an abstraction of a more complex script. The goal is to get information from unread emails and add it to a CSV file.
It also needs to check whether the file exists in the first place. To simplify I put print statements instead of function calls. This still brings up the issue.

```
import ezgmail
import csv

orderEmails = ezgmail.search('subject:Automatic message, label:UNREAD')
unreadThreads = ezgmail.unread()
amountMessages = len(orderEmails[0].messages)
number: int
for number in range(amountMessages):
    message = orderEmails[0].messages[number]
    date = message.timestamp
    try:
        with open('file.csv','r') as file:
            csvReader = csv.reader(file, delimiter=',')
                for row in csvReader:
                    if row[0] == date:
                        print("Timestamp already exists")
                    else:
                        print("Ok")
    except FileNotFoundError:
        print("No such file")
```

Contents of file.csv

```
Date,Name,City
2020-12-27 18:11:16,John,New York
2020-12-29 17:44:23,Mary,Berlin
```

The variable "date" should be this string in the first run of the loop:

```
2020-12-27 18:11:16
```

Then this one:

```
2020-12-30 12:51:32
```

What I expected to get is:

```
Timestamp already exists
Ok
```

What I get instead is:

```
Ok
Ok
Ok
Ok
Ok
Ok
```

Besides obviously not understanding why this happens, I also don't understand why 6 "Ok" messages.

Comment: Add a `print(date)` line after `for row in csvReader` to see if you can identify your problem.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. This is what I get now, after adding next(csvReader)

2020-12-27 18:11:16
Ok
2020-12-27 18:11:16
Ok
2020-12-30 12:51:32
Ok
2020-12-30 12:51:32
Ok

Answer (score 0):

You're iterating over `csvReader`, which **yields you the header row, too**.

```py
# First row
['Date', 'Name', 'City']

# Second row
['2020-12-27 18:11:16', 'John', 'New York']

# Third row
['2020-12-29 17:44:23', 'Mary', 'Berlin']
```

String `'Date'` doesn't equal to string `'2020-12-27 18:11:16'`, so the `print("Ok")` branch of your IF is executed.

---

As to why `6 "Ok" messages` are being printed - I guess you're doing all that multiple times - because of the number stored in variable `amountMessages`.

```py
for number in range(amountMessages):
   ...
```

---

#### Bonus LPT (Life Pro Tip)

If unsure, often the easiest thing to do is to **put interactive debugger in there** - and you can inspect variables at that point during execution.

If you have Python `<3.7`, you can simply put `import pdb; pdb.set_trace()` inside your code, like this:

```
...
    for row in csvReader:
        import pdb; pdb.set_trace()
        if row[0] == date
        ...
...
```

... and run your code. This way you will get interactive debugging session at that point, where you can do things like...

```
(Pdb) yay = 123
(Pdb) yay
123
(Pdb) row[0]
'Date'
```

If you have Python `>=3.7`, the built-in `breakpoint()` function is available, which you can use instead.

More info about `pdb` at Python official docs: https://docs.python.org/3/library/pdb.html

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I now added the line next(csvReader) and get 4 "Ok" instead of six. Guess that's an improvement. The variable amountMessages == 2

Comment: `4 "Ok"`s seems about right. You're iterating over `two CSV lines` multiplied by `two messages`.

Comment: Thanks! Using Pdb I discovered that the timestamp was formatted differently. However, when printed, it shows the same format as I exposed before. To be clear:
print(date) => 2020-12-27 18:11:16, whereas (Pdb) date => datetime.datetime(2020, 12, 27, 18, 11, 16)